# When or how to delete QThread in Qt

Tags: windows, multithreading, qt

I found this QThread example from [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/note_revisions/5/8/view). It recommends to use QObject and QThread over than subclassing QThread.

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void doWork() {
        /* ... */
    }
};

QThread *thread = new QThread;
Worker *worker = new Worker;
worker->moveToThread(thread);
thread->start();
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(worker, "doWork", Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

My first question is when and how to delete the thread?

I have tried to connect finished to 2 slots, myTest and deleteLater. And I set a breakpoint in myTest, this never got triggered. So I suspect there is no finished signal, which mean the thread would not be deleted.

```
connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(myTest()));
```

For the worker object, I emit a finished signal as the last instruction in doWork, and connect it to a slot in which I can delete the worker object. Is this the right way?

Qt version: 4.6.2

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to release memory of Qthread object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714492/how-to-release-memory-of-qthread-object)

Comment: Just connect the thread `finished()` signal first to the worker and then to the thread's own `deleteLater()` slot

Comment: Something has to tell the thread to [quit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qthread.html#quit), otherwise it will never emit the [`finished`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qthread.html#finished) signal.

Comment: Ops, seems that my last comment only works for versions of Qt after 4.8, it will likely not work in 4.6.2.

Comment: emit some signal in your `Worker` at the end of `doWork` function and connect it to quit() slot of thread just before connection finished to deleteLater() etc

Comment: Thank you guys. Suppose I can make the thread life span the same as mainwindow, but for learning purpose, if I want to finish the thread earlier, should I manually call  thread->exit() and assign it back to null? Or like @Shf said, connect signal to quit slot before connect finished to deleteLater?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your thread exits normally when its `worker` method execution completed, but if you want to do some things in thread exit time, use the `finished()` signal and it is possible to deallocate objects that live in thread that has just ended, by connecting the `finished()` signal to `QObject::deleteLater()`:

```
connect(workerThread, &WorkerThread::finished, workerThread, &QObject::deleteLater);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method of deleting later `thread` using `connect()` statement should work.

Your suggested method of deleting later `worker` after it is `finished()` should also work.

However, in order to trigger your slot `myTest()`, you will need to add more code:

1. When `worker` is `finished()`, use `connect()` statements to call `thread->quit()`, `worker->deleteLater()`, and `this->deleteLater()`.
2. Use `Qt::DirectConnection` in the above `connect()` statements.

Following is a test example to implement the above solution, assuming that your class is named `Tester`:

File `worker.h`:

```
#ifndef WORKER_H
#define WORKER_H

#include <QObject>

class Worker : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker();
    ~Worker();
signals:
    void finished();
public slots:
    void doWork();
};

#endif // WORKER_H
```

File `worker.cpp`:

```
#include "worker.h"

#include <QDebug>

Worker::Worker()
{
    qDebug() << "D/Worker==Worker";
}

Worker::~Worker()
{
    qDebug() << "D/Worker==~Worker";
}

void Worker::doWork()
{
    qDebug() << "D/Worker==doWork";

    // Do work here

    emit finished();
}
```

File `tester.h`:

```
#ifndef TESTER_H
#define TESTER_H

#include <QObject>

class Tester : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Tester();
    ~Tester();
public:
    void startTesting();
public slots:
    void myTest();
};

#endif // TESTER_H
```

File `tester.cpp`:

```
#include "tester.h"

#include "worker.h"

#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>

Tester::Tester()
{
    qDebug() << "D/Tester==Tester";
}

Tester::~Tester()
{
    qDebug() << "D/Tester==~Tester";
}

void Tester::startTesting()
{
    qDebug() << "D/Tester==startTesting";

    QThread * thread = new QThread;
    Worker * worker = new Worker;
    worker->moveToThread(thread);
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()), Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), this,   SLOT(myTest()),      Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()),        Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater()), Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), this,   SLOT(deleteLater()), Qt::DirectConnection);
    thread->start();
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(worker, "doWork", Qt::QueuedConnection);

    // "thread" is deleted later.
    // "worker" is deleted later.
}

void Tester::myTest()
{
    qDebug() << "D/Tester==myTest";
}
```

File `main.cpp`:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

#include "worker.h"
#include "tester.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qDebug() << "D/TestQThreadNewDelete==main";

    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Tester * tester = new Tester;

    tester->startTesting();

    // "tester" is deleted later in tester->onWorkerFinished().

    return a.exec();
}
```

The output of running this test application, using Qt 5.5.0 on Linux, is as follows:

```
D/TestQThreadNewDelete==main
D/Tester==Tester
D/Tester==startTesting
D/Worker==Worker
D/Worker==doWork
D/Tester==myTest
D/Worker==~Worker
D/Tester==~Tester
```

from which we can see that:

1. Slot `Tester::myTest()` was triggered.
2. Therefore, signal `QThread::finished()` should have been emitted earlier.
3. Similarly, slot `QThread::deleteLater()` would be triggered also. This is likely to happen when the test application exits. However, debugging would be needed in order to confirm this, which I have not tried.

Comment: The last connect with Qt::DirectConnection is wrong and will make your app crash, as the Tester will be destroyed in the sub-thread. Don't mess with DirectConnection and threads.

Comment: You are right. My mistake of not going through each line to check. So don't use `Qt::DirectConnection` in the last `connect` statement. Thanks for pointing this out.